# Looking for advice/help on how to fix rigging/deformation of the shoulder

Tags: rigging

[image]

I'm pretty sure the shoulder isn't supposed to look like this while rotating, but I don't know how to get that properly look as I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to rigging. Can anyone point me to a guide on proper shoulder movement as I don't know where to start looking. I have also included a [gif](https://gyazo.com/82a27e5097dd0b3a0218b5190c3c7a2e) of the shoulder rotating as well.

Comment: you probably need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

The Best advice I can give you is to learn to distribute the rotations in your mesh bendigs. This can be archived in mainly 2 ways. Correct weight painting and/or correct bone placement. If you do not like painting then be aware that the number of bones Will be increased and its placement should be less forgiving with bendigs. But the Main priority should be the Distribution of rotating loops along specific áreas of the shoulders, forearms, hips, calves etc. Also you should stablish when and how this rotations need to ocurr. https://youtu.be/vR8eji6Y45c